# LocationListener is being called multiple times

Tags: android

I am working on an Location Based Application. In this application I am using LocationListener class to update the location when the Location is changed. In each Activity i have different LocationListener to update location and do some specific work on updated location.

But my problem is that when I am changing my location through DDMS, the LocationListener is being called of that current Activity as well as all the activities of the whole application where LocationListener has been defined. I don't know whether there should be one LocationListener for the whole application or for each Activity we should have different LocationListener.

Comment: That your question is urgent to you isn't relevant to us. This site isn't some kind of 24/7 paid support service. Well, not that I'm stopping you from sending us send some money.. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that you *unregister* your `LocationListeners` any time you leave an `Activity`.

You'll know if you've left `LocationListeners` open if you see the GPS icon flashing at in the status bar, even after you've left your application.

If you really need a long-lived `LocationListener` for your application, you could put this into a `Service`.